# How to tell qmake where to find the unixODBC header files and shared libraries?

Tags: qt, qt5, unixodbc

I've tried to follow the instructions on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qodbc to configure QODBC driver.
So I download it from http://www.unixodbc.org and extact it in "/usr/local" directory.

[image: /usr/local directory]

Then I tried to tell qmake where to find the unixODBC header files and shared libraries, so I typed the following command in terminal "qmake -- ODBC_PREFIX=/usr/local/unixODBC-2.3.7"

terminal description

[image]

However it doesn't work.

Comment: what are your OS and Qt version?

Comment: @eyllanesc ubuntu 19.04 and qt 5.14

Comment: How have you installed Qt?

Comment: sudo apt-get install qtcreator -y

Comment: that only installs qtcreator, but doesn't install qt

Comment: I really didn't understand what you said.. but I have worked on it for months and I did many projects, But when I wanted to configure odbc I stucked... how to install qt then if this is the main problem?

Comment: execute:  `sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-odbc`. If you have installed Qt using the ubuntu repo then it is not necessary to compile the plugin as it already exists.

Comment: Well I typed that command and it's installed successfully and I can see that the "libqsqlodbc.so" is added newly to the sqldriver folder ,so I tried to connect qt to the sql database and hopefully the "QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded" message disappeared but the db is not connected... any other suggestions please??

Comment: If you don't tell me how you installed Qt then it is difficult to help you

Comment: all I remember is that command I typed.. I think it would be easier if you tell me the right way to install qt5 on ubuntu ,then I will try to reinstall it properly

Comment: 1) remove all Qt installed and execute: `sudo apt-get install qt5-default qttools5-dev`